# Golang stuct validation

Tags: validation, go

Good day! I gave a config file:

```
type Config struct {
    SettingsID *string  `mapstructure:"settingsId" validate:"required"`
}
```

I use go-playground/validator/v10 for struct validation.

My SettingsID field can have only letters (a-z), numbers(0-9), can have only some symbols ( _ - \ ) and to be in lower case.

Now I check it via regexp [a-z0-9_-]  and it works fine. But is there a way to check it via struct tags? I wanted to do something like

```
SettingsID *string `mapstructure:"settingsId" validate:"required,lowercase,alphanum,containsany=_\\-"`
```

But it doesnt work - ***containsany*** tells that a string MUST contain some of the symbols, etc.

Is there a way to make validation work via tags?

Comment: `containsany` needs atleast one of the symbols to be present. And no other validation can be used _just_ with tags

Comment: One way would be to define a custom validator function, that receives your struct and iterates over the runes of `SettingsID` to check if special character other than the ones you have defined are not present.

Comment: Inian, but I could use my regexp in that function and do the trick. The question is - is it possible to do the task with tags only?

Comment: Don't think it exists. You could raise a new issue on the project GitHub page

Comment: This is why the package allows you to add custom validators though...